# Write a thinner view in django ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a sample project as follow [github link](https://github.com/jakiro2017/jubilant-waddle). The problem is the logic handles mostly on view, not serializers. I read it as a bad practice:

```
class OrgAddAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.root_nodes()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        alldata = request.POST
        # desc = alldata.get("desc", "0")
        # name = alldata.get("name", "0")
        desc = request.data.get("desc")
        name = request.data.get("name")
        code = request.data.get("code")
        subpath = request.data.get("subpath")
        try:
            parent = Organization.objects.root_nodes().get()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.__class__.__name__)
            if e.__class__.__name__ == "DoesNotExist":
                parent = Organization.objects.create(name="BOSS", desc="boss",code="BOSS",subpath="ftech")
            else:
                response_dict = {"c" : ErrorCode.ORG_GENERIC_ERROR,  "m": str(e),
                                 "e" : ErrorCode(ErrorCode.ORG_GENERIC_ERROR.name)}
                return Response(response_dict)

        try:
            Organization.objects.create(name=name, desc=desc, code = code, subpath =subpath, parent=parent)
        except Exception as e:
            response_dict = {"c" : ErrorCode.ORG_GENERIC_ERROR, "m": str(e),
                             "e" : ErrorCode.ORG_GENERIC_ERROR.name}
            return Response(response_dict)

        response_dict = {"result": "true"}
        # update response_dict with whatever you want to send in response
        return Response(response_dict)
```

I tried to refactor to serializer but it not jump to the new function:

```
class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)
    def validate(self,data):
        """ //// not jump
        check that root node must be available
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        serialized = jsonpickle.encode(data)
        print(yaml.dump(yaml.load(serialized), indent=2))

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data.get("name", None) // not jump
        serialized = jsonpickle.encode(validated_data)
        print(yaml.dump(yaml.load(serialized), indent=2))
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'code' , 'subpath' , 'desc', 'parent_id', 'level', 'children')
```

What did I do wrong? Sorry if this sound noob question.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the logic handles mostly on view...

I would say **everything**. The problem is that you're not using the serializer in your view. You can see [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/764dabd29e127a0b1a07794f8268a1b1535d9507/rest_framework/mixins.py#L12) the "by default" implementation of the create method. It uses `get_serializer` which in the end is using `serializer_class` class attribute. Follow that approach and it will jump where you want.